# how to export rows of a file having specific number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a file which has thousands of rows with varying columns. The file type is a .msh file which can be also opened with a text reader. All the data are also separated by space. The view of my file:

```
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$Nodes
2929
1 26.66002035140991 0.75 1.25
2 71.57912731170654 0.75 98.75
3 71.57912731170654 29.25 98.75
...
```

Now, I want to extract the rows that have 9 columns. I tried the following code, but it gives me each row as a string rather than separated columns of integers or floats:

```
with open('my_file') as f:
    saved_lines = [line for line in f if len(line.split()) == 9]
```

then, it gives:

```
'2675 4 2 0 1 25 27 1223 2073\n',
'2676 4 2 0 1 252 272 271 1904\n',
'2677 4 2 0 1 271 251 252 1904\n',
...
```

while I need to get the results as an array of values:

```
[[2675, 4, 2, 0, 1, 25, 27, 1223, 2073]
 [2676, 4, 2, 0, 1, 252, 272, 271, 1904]
 [2677, 4, 2, 0, 1, 271, 251, 252, 1904]
 ...]]
```

I appreciate if anyone help me solve that. I appreciate nay solution in numpy or pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the splitted line, you currently save the entire line. Try this:

```
with open('my_file') as f:
    saved_lines = [line.split() for line in f if len(line.split()) == 9]
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It worked perfect. Just it was giving each number as a string which was easily changed to ints or floats using saved_lines[saved_lines == ''] = 0.0 and then, saved_lines = saved_lines.astype(np.int).

Answer (score 1):

Two more steps:

1. Split the result line
2. Convert the result to a `numpy` array:

```py
import numpy as np

with open("my_file", "r") as f:
    saved_lines = np.array([line.split() for line in f if len(line.split()) == 9])

print(saved_lines)
```